# How libraries work? Trying to install mouseinfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm trying to create a script for AutoKey (Linux) that uses the 'mouseinfo' module. I did:

```
pip3 install mouseinfo
I ran this line while I use in
~/.config/autokey/data/My_Scripts
```

but when I try to

```
import mouseinfo
```

in my python script, it seems it can't find it.

I don't really know how the python libraries are organised and how to properly use them.

```
python3 -m site
sys.path = [
'/home/myusr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python36.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.6',
'/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/myusr/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/myusr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

and after

```
cd /home/myusr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
ls
```

I get a list of packages and I can see mouseinfo there. What's next?

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Another try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
Successfully installed mouseinfo-0.1.3
pip3 install mouseinfo
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Makd9.png)

and as you can see, the module is installed (I think).

Still, nothing.

I'm on Reolith Linux (Ubuntu latest version), using ZSh and Vim (and Python 3, of course), if it matters.

What's next?

Edit: I tried to install Xlib as well, same story, can't import it. I am obviously doing something wrong due to my Python ignorance, but can't figure out what.

Edit 2: installed virtualenv plugin for Vim, but :VirtualEnvList return 'Not an editor command'.

Edit 3: activated venv and also:

```
source env/bin/activate
~/.config/autokey/data/My_Scripts
pip install mouseinfo
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-Xlib; platform_system == "Linux" and python_version >= "3.0" in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=4.0.0; python_version == "3.6" in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (1.8.0)

pip3 install mouseinfo
Requirement already satisfied: mouseinfo in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=4.0.0; python_version == "3.6" in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-Xlib; platform_system == "Linux" and python_version >= "3.0" in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from mouseinfo) (0.15)
```

It seems that I can import the module after running python3 in the terminal. Problem is with Vim probably. Any ideas?

Comment: try running `which pip3` as well to see if it is in the same "bin" as the python3 you are using

Comment: Thanks @MarkAWard! So after which pip3 (/home/idankor/.local/bin/pip3) and which python3 (/usr/bin/python3), what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

As your default `pip3` and `python3` are in different locations you can try installing the package by first invoking your desired python installation and calling out to pip

```
python3 -m pip install mouseinfo
```

Comment: well if you had pip3 successful install the package instead of running python3 you try running `/home/idankor/.local/bin/python`

Comment: no such file or directory: /home/myusr/.local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up on Vim and use Visual Studio Code, and to use pyautogui's position instead. This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

1: pip3 install mouseinfo
2: sudo apt-get install scrot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).